# How to make Spring server to start even if database is down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, fail-fast

I'm using a Spring Boot(1.4.7) & MyBatis.

```
spring.main1.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://192.168.0.11:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&socketTimeout=5000&connectTimeout=3000
spring.main1.datasource.username=username
spring.main1.datasource.password=password
spring.main1.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout=5000
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval=5000
spring.main1.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=5000
spring.main1.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

I cannot start program with errors when database is disconnected on Eclipse or Linux server.
(Database is not located on localhost.)

When I try to start program with disconnected database, 
print this.

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=192.168.0.11)(port=3306)(type=master) : connect timed out
Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=192.168.0.11)(port=3306)(type=master) : connect timed out
Stopping service [Tomcat]
Application startup failed
```

Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: This maybe fixed in a later Spring Boot release. According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7589 try upgrading to at least 1.5.2?

Comment: Could exception handling prove somewhat useful?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set:

```
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
```

in your application.properties.

According to the [Spring Boot 2.5.5 user guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.5/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc):

> By default, Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of its script-based database initializer. This means that, if the scripts cause exceptions, the application fails to start. You can tune that behavior by setting `spring.sql.init.continue-on-error`.

P.S.: Before Spring Boot 2.5, the property was named `spring.datasource.continue-on-error`.

Comment: This is not working with 2.1.1.RELEASE or the one older than this

Comment: According to the Spring Boot 2.1.1 user guide this should work.

Comment: I am using these config:spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

Comment: in addition to an MSSQLDbConfig class initializing the entityManagerFactory

Comment: I added both properties: spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true & spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect. But, it fails with the error UnsatisfiedDependencyException for the repository with nested exception IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type for my class annotated with @Entity.

Comment: Adding `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` to `application.yml` file doesn't seem to work for Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE.  We are on Oracle DB.

Comment: According to the documentation this seems to be applicable for Flyway intialization, thus if the script fails, it resumes.

Comment: Not working anymore I guess

Comment: @cristi_nmr The name of the property is now `spring.sql.init.continue-on-error`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Will it try to connect again when any query is made?

Answer (score 18):

I was able to solve this. One main difference between what I got working and the code in the question, though, is that I'm using Hikari instead of Tomcat for the connection pool.

These were the key settings I had to make:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle: 0
spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-timeout: -1
spring.datasource.continue-on-error: true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Setting `minimum-idle` to 0 allows Hikari to be happy without any connections.

The `initialization-fail-timeout` setting of -1 tells Hikari that I don't want it to get a connection when the pool fires up.

From the [HikariCP documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP):

> A value less than zero will bypass any initial connection attempt, and the pool will start immediately while trying to obtain connections in the background. Consequently, later efforts to obtain a connection may fail.

The `continue-on-error` setting `true` allows the service to continue even when encountering an error.

Both the `driver-class-name` and `database-platform` were required. Otherwise, Hikari tries to figure out those values by connecting to the database (during startup).

---

Just in case I'm missing something, though, here's my full Spring config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <redacted>
  datasource:
    url: <redacted>
    username: <redacted>
    password: <redacted>
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 0
      maximum-pool-size: 15
      connection-timeout: 10000 #10s
      idle-timeout: 300000 #5m
      max-lifetime: 600000 #10m
      initialization-fail-timeout: -1
      validation-timeout: 1000 #1s
    continue-on-error: true
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

And my project has the following Spring Boot dependencies:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

in order to make it works

Comment: This was the only setting I needed to add. It works without needing `continue-on-error`.

Answer (score 1):

If the tips above didn't help and you use jpa, then set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

it worked for me.

Comment: It also worked in my case. **None** of the following properties were required: `spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true`, `spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle: 0`, 
`spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-timeout: -1`. Database: PostgreSQL. Spring Boot & Spring-Data-Jpa: 3.1.5

Answer (score -4):

When you build your app you can add that

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

it will skip the tests of database connection

*(-D is used to define a system property)*