# How to make micro service start if the Liquibase bean fails due to databse connection failure

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, liquibase-hibernate

I have a java spring boot application working with MS SQL Server. The DB scripts run with Liquibase.
The issue I'm facing is that if the connection to DB fails, the service fails to initialize. I don't want to force a connection to DB in order to make the service start. Service should not be dependent on connection success.
**Application.yml Configuration:**
[Application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d9jU.png)

**Error I'm getting:**

*Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-14 20:39:25,378 | main | ERROR | search | o.s.boot.SpringApplication | SpringApplication::reportFailure: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information.. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at com.nice.mcr.search.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information.. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)*

Comment: Trying to understand your set up, do you want this to run only in local or in production aswell? Either way this question and answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409196/how-to-make-spring-server-to-start-even-if-database-is-down

Comment: Hi, also locally and also on production - I don't want to fail service from start if the connection fails

Comment: Bad time to edit my comment, but i added a link that might help you to a similar question.

Comment: The solutions from the link unfortunately not fixing my issue. If I set Liquibase-enalbed  to false the service succeeds to start, so maybe in the link, they are not using liquibase. thanks any way.