# spring boot application with multiple databases

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application configured two databases into it. The application is starting and working fine when both the databases are up and running. But I want to make it up and running for the scenario when first database is reachable and second database is not reachable. Can someone help on this.

Comment: Have a look at creating the second datasource programmatically via DataSourceBuilder. See [link][https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic]

Comment: Hi, please see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409196/how-to-make-spring-server-to-start-even-if-database-is-down

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Spring server to start even if database is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409196/how-to-make-spring-server-to-start-even-if-database-is-down)